# shell scripting using regular expression pattern matching

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I have a file say abc.txt which contains..

```
<mapping number=1 name=m1> 
<transformation type=aggregator name=agg_m1> /> 
<transformation type=joiner name=j_m1 /> 
</mapping>

<mapping number=2 name=m2> 
<transformation type=router name=rtr_m2> /> 
<transformation type=joiner name=j_m2 /> 
</mapping>
```

I neen an output of the form of the same order. i.e, i need to get name field from mapping and type and name fields from transformation "in the same order  :

```
name=m1
type=aggregator name=agg_m1
type=joiner name=j_m1
name=m2
type=router name=rtr_m2
type=joiner name=j_m2
```

I have used the command 'awk' to get the output , but I am getting it of the following form which is incorrect :

```
name=m1
name=m2
type=aggregator name=agg_m1
type=joiner name=j_m1
type=router name=rtr_m2
type=joiner name=j_m2
```

I tried using 'grep' and 'sed' commands too but I am getting the desired output, because the order is not preserved. I need to the get the output where the order is preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 perl -lne '$_=~m/^[^\s]*\s([^\/\>]*)/g;print $1' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
<mapping number=1 name=m1>
<transformation type=aggregator name=agg_m1> />
<transformation type=joiner name=j_m1 />
</mapping>

<mapping number=2 name=m2>
<transformation type=router name=rtr_m2> />
<transformation type=joiner name=j_m2 />
</mapping>
> perl -lne '$_=~m/^[^\s]*\s([^\/\>]*)/g;print $1' temp
number=1 name=m1
type=aggregator name=agg_m1
type=joiner name=j_m1


number=2 name=m2
type=router name=rtr_m2
type=joiner name=j_m2

>
```

If you do not need `number`,then use the below regex:

```
perl -lne '$_=~m/^[^\s]*\s[number=\d]*([^\/\>]*)/g;print $1' your_file
```

Comment: Hello Sarathi, 
Thank you for your reply. I will try your solution. I have very less knowledge in perl. But I am able to understand the command. and also I do not need the "number" field from the <mapping.. 
I need only the "name" field. The problem is the no. of attributes such as (number, name, etc.. ) for each <mapping.. is different.

Comment: Thanks Sarathi. That'll do :)

Comment: If you got what you need,Pls donot forget to accept the answer whichever you feel worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `grep`:

```
grep -oE "(name|type)=[^ >]* *[^ >]*" file
```

Results:

```
name=m1
type=aggregator name=agg_m1
type=joiner name=j_m1
name=m2
type=router name=rtr_m2
type=joiner name=j_m2
```

Comment: Hello Steve, 
Thank you for your reply. I will consider your solution and try it out and will update you on the same.